Generalization of subadditivity analogous to quasiconvexity, and variants
I am curious if there are natural generalizations of subadditivity which have been studied in the past or have been stated in the literature? I (and people that I have talked to) have not had much success finding anything.
Let me make my question more precise.
Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is subadditive: that is, it satisfies
$$f(n+m)\leq f(n)+f(m)$$
for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. It's pretty well-known (Fekete's lemma) that, defining $g(n)=f(n)/n$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}g(n).
$$
Actually, $g(n)$ is "sort of convex", in that
$$
g(n+m)\leq \frac{n\cdot g(n)+m\cdot g(m)}{n+m}.
$$
So, a natural choice one might make is to replace the above condition with a "sort of quasiconvex" condition. Suppose $g$ satisfies
$$
g(n+m) \leq \max\{g(n),g(m)\}
$$
for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Unfortunately, this isn't actually enough to guarantee existence of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$: a simple counterexample is given by the function
$$
g(n) = \begin{cases}
1 &: n\text{ odd},\newline
0 &: n\text{ even}.
\end{cases}
$$
So therefore it is sensible to also add a mild continuity condition, such as: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\leq \delta n$,
$$
g(n+m)\leq g(n)+\epsilon.
$$
With this additional hypothesis, the proof that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}g(n)$ is essentially the same as the usual proof of Fekete's lemma.
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we may write $n = \ell k + j$ for $0<j\leq k$ and $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$. Then taking $\delta$ from the continuity condition (depending on $\epsilon$) and $n$ sufficiently large so that $\delta \cdot \ell \geq 1$, applying the continuity condition and then the quasiconvexity condition $\ell-1$ times
$$
g(n) = g(\ell k + j)\leq g(\ell k)+\epsilon \leq g(k)+\epsilon.
$$
Thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}g(n)\leq g(k)+\epsilon$. Since $k$ and $\epsilon$ are arbitrary, we're done.
It is easy to check that subadditivity implies the quasiconvex property along with the continuity property (in fact, we can even take $\delta=\epsilon$). Actually, this condition feels very natural to me and it was very useful to me recently since I "morally" had a subadditivity property, but could not actually establish subadditivity in practice.
Here are my questions:

Does this generalization of subadditivity have a name in the literature?
Is there a more natural continuity assumption which would still work?
In some sense, convexity is an "$L^1$" condition and quasiconvexity is an "$L^\infty$" condition. Are there any natural "$L^p$" conditions for $1<p<\infty$, either between convexity and quasiconvexity, or indeed between subadditivity and the property defined above?

